# Simplepie: How to display full blog post?

Tags: php, wordpress, simplepie

Sample Post: http://oi43.tinypic.com/huq3o6.jpg

Using the $item->get_description() function - I am only getting a part of the blog posts description. It truncates after 50-60 words.

How do I get the full post?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know simplepie, but a quick Google search told me that `$item->get_description()` returns, well, a description. Try using `get_content()`

Documentation for `get_description()`

http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_description

Documentation for `get_content()`

http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_content